# Как задать фон-картинку div?

Tags: css

Как div сделать фон-картинку? Для body получается, а для div нет...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Lr3phs6j/

если фоновое изображение без контента - задавайте высоту

Comment: Спасибо. То что нужно!